# Binding custom datasource to SPCalenderView

Tags: calendar

I am wondering if it is possible to create a custom data source, fill it through code, and bind it to the SPCalenderView.

I searched various places but didn't find any example code which explains binding custom data source to SPCalenderView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a code-based solution you can use the SPCalendarView control, which could bind to any type of data. Look here for a full-blown example http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/09/custom-calendar-webpart-in-sharepoint.html